# jQuery or Canvas Screensaver for website with timeout on site back to screensaver page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeout, html5-canvas

I have a multipage site that the main home page simply has a single image logo on it.  When this page is visited I need the image to move around like a screensaver.  When any touch is registered the page will go to a second page.  That second page has other data and info but nothing is touched for ten minutes it will default and go back to the entry page and the screensaver.

So, two things.

One, move an image around like a screensaver using jQuery.
Two, the other page has a timeout of ten minutes if no touch is registered that knocks the person back to the first page that has the screensaver.

This is an HTML5 page so if jQuery will not work, something using HTML5 and Canvas might.

This is for a site that will be used as a kiosk and a touch screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the screensaver page:**

You can use an html canvas that floats your logo image around the screen.  Here's a link:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/E3Qda/

**On the second page:**

How about starting a 10 minute setTimeout when the page first loads.

If the user triggers a touch event before 10 minutes, (1) clearTimeout the original timeout (2) setTimeout for a new 10 minutes.

Here's example code for the screensaver page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    img{border:1px solid purple;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var ball;
        var ballX=60;
        var ballY=150;
        var ballRadius=50;

        var image=new Image();
        image.onload=function(){

            // resize the image to fit inside the ball's radius
            var c=document.createElement("canvas");
            var cctx=c.getContext("2d");

            // calc the max side length of a square that fits the ball
            var maxSide=Math.sqrt(2*ballRadius*ballRadius);

            // calc the max rect size that fits in the ball
            var iw=image.width;
            var ih=image.height;
            var maxW,maxH;
            if(iw>=ih){
                maxW=maxSide;
                maxH=maxSide*iw/ih;
            }else{
                maxW=maxSide*ih/iw;
                maxH=maxSide;
            }

            // size the temp canvas to the max rect size
            c.width=maxW;
            c.height=maxH;

            // draw the image to the temp canvas
            cctx.drawImage(image,0,0,iw,ih,0,0,maxW,maxH);


        var ballimg=new Image();
        ballimg.onload=function(){
            ball={x:ballX,y:ballY,r:ballRadius,img:ballimg,imgSide:maxSide,directionX:1,directionY:1};
            drawBall(ball);
        }
        ballimg.src=c.toDataURL();

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        }
        image.src="ship.png";

        function drawBall(ball){

            // clip image inside ball
            ctx.save();
            ctx.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.clip();

            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillRect(ball.x-ball.r,ball.y-ball.r,ball.r*2,ball.r*2);
            ctx.drawImage(ball.img, ball.x-ball.imgSide/2,ball.y-ball.imgSide/2);
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.strokeStyle="lightgray";
            ctx.lineWidth=2;
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.r+2,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
            ctx.lineWidth=2;
            ctx.stroke();
        }


        function animate(time) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            // move with collision detection
            ball.x+=ball.directionX;
            if(ball.x-ball.r<0 || ball.x+ball.r>canvas.width){
                ball.directionX*=-1;
                ball.x+=ball.directionX;
            }
            ball.y+=ball.directionY;
            if(ball.y-ball.r<0 || ball.y+ball.r>canvas.height){
                ball.directionY*=-1;
                ball.y+=ball.directionY;
            }

            // Draw
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            drawBall(ball);
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```